# expressing your attitude towards something

Tags: sentence-choice

I have recently watched a movie which is really great and now I'm trying to express my attitude towards this movie. Here is what I want to say:

> I'm wondering how a movie can be so complicated and at the same time
>   very interesting.

Is this sentence correct grammatically (or meaning) ? How do natives state this?

Comment: Native speakers might use exactly the same words as you yourself (except it's a bit of a trite observation, since people are *usually* more interested in "complicated" situations that "trivial" ones). But since you haven't given any reason for why you doubt your own phrasing, I think this is essentially "proofreading".

Comment: @FumbleFingers The only reason is that I'm not native and I thought it might sound awkward (grammatically and through meaning). Thanks anyway

Comment: But you must have *some* reason why you *thought it might sound awkward.* If you *edit the question* to explain what that reason is, your question will probably get answered and you might learn something useful. But if you don't do that, it will almost certainly be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing intrinsically wrong with your sentence. However, I would expect a native speaker to be more likely to say:

> I'm wondering how a movie can be so complicated and at the same time **so** very interesting.

This balances the use of 'so' as an intensive on both sides of the sentence.  Also, the expression 'so very + something' is quite common.

I agree with FumbleFingers' observation that 'people are usually more interested in "complicated" situations that "trivial" ones'.

Comment: Is there a better word to be used instead of "complicated"?

Comment: @Ayhan Buyuk  There is nothing wrong with the word 'complicated' itself, it is more the fact that your sentence implies that complicated movies are not very interesting. This is true for some people, but there are many others who prefer a complex plot that requires them to think, than a simple plot that is utterly predictable. Complicated movies can be very popular. For example, *Pulp Fiction* has a very convoluted, non-linear storyline, but many people loved it. The following words are often used to describe movies that are complicated; complex, convoluted, intricate, elaborate.